# How to organize jUnit tests to separately cover packages and entire program?

Tags: java, junit, package

This question is about your experience and industry best practices. 
Please comment on what i did and see whether it makes sence. Let me know how you handle the same problem

When i write my tests, i usually focus on on package at a time. Each class in src gets its own test class. Life is good. For a given package, i come up with a single class that is responsible for running all tests in a package. For example (`A.java`) that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { One.class, Two.class, Three.class })
public class _A {

}
```

**Concern 1: This introduces 1 extra class that is used to run all tests for that package.**

**Concern 2: My tendency is to precede that class with an underscore (to make sure it shows up on top. Understore (i was told), is a bad taste ..**

**Question: Is it common to create a separate test class to test a given package?**

Pattern as shown above repeats for every package i have. For each package i have under /test, i have an _Package{x}Tests.java

Additionally, at the root directory under /test, i have a mother of all tests class which includes all package tests

```
/test
    _ApplicationTests.class

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( { _A.class, _B.class, _C.class })
public class _ApplicationTests {

}
```

**Concern 1: I really would rather avoid default package, but at the same time, i like very much to see "first test that shows up" to be the master test file**

**Concern 2: Again (i must have read this somewhere .. ) MasterTests class starts with an underscore (for consistency i gues**)

How do you guys handle this? Is what i described an acceptable approach?

For me (personally), i am very attracked to the idea of having an option to run "all tests" and "all package tests" separately.

Thanks, and please let me know.

Comment: what IDE are you using? In Eclipse you can specify which packages (single Tests, all Tests) should be tested. I usually run only selected tests, and let the build automation execute every single Test.
Do you need the Suites for anything or just convenience?

Comment: I use Eclipse. How do you specify what tests a ran? All/ Package? Reason is convenience. I really like to be able to tech either everything or a package at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, you can right click on a test package and run all tests in it.

If you're using maven and surefire/failsafe, you can specify the package(s) using `-Dtest=com.package.*` (which is more powerful than Eclipse since you can start at the top of a nested package hierarchy). Ant might have a similar option.

Either approach means you don't need your custom @Suite classes.

Comment: Thanks, this works. For some reason the obvious solutions always escape from me. Shift-Alt-X,T runs jUnit nice and clean without any @Suite classes

Comment: Yeah it's a cool feature. Now they need to extend it to allow you to select multiple packages and run all of them.